# Trouble replacing middle of content with JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text

`name[one][1][two][45][text]`

I catch the text "45" using this pattern

```
/(.*?)rows\]\[([0-9]*)(.*)/;
```

But how can I replace the only 45 with any other digit? Because if I use the same pattern with replace method, it replacing the entrire previous word. My code is

```
var name = "name[one][1][two][45][text]";
var pattern = /(.*?)two\]\[([0-9]*)(.*)/;
var number = name.match(pattern);
number = parseInt(number[2]);

var replacePattern = /(.*?)two\]\[([0-9]*)/;
var newName = name.replace(replacePattern, parseInt(number + 2));
console.log(newName);
```

But it's returning **47][text]**

Comment: So, you're trying to replace the numbers from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I replace the only 45 with any other digit?

You can use the replace function with matching groups :

For example — Here I replace the `45` with `7` :

```
   "name[one][1][two][45][text]".replace(/(.*?)(two\]\[)([0-9]*)(.*)/,function (a,b,c,d,e){
        // replace 7 with what you want
        return b+c+'7'+e;
    })
```

[Result](http://jsbin.com/rusivalapu/edit?html,js,output) :

```
"name[one][3][two][7][text]"
```

Notice i've added `()` to include other parts which I can later , add together.

Edit: regarding to your actual example (+=2) : [you can do this](http://jsbin.com/rusivalapu/edit?html,js,output) :

```
return b+c+(parseInt(d)+2)+e; -- to your actual example
```

Comment: @user1936285 mmm every day in SO , I can see how i'm not but it is always good to learn...

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there will only be `2` numbers then

```
([0-9]+)(?!.*?\d)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0sZ0/1

Answer (score 0):

String.replace allows a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as the second argument, which will be called for each regex match. You can perform the addition(or any other calculation) inside that function.
With a slight modification of the regex, using capturing groups differently, you can achieve this -
Try this -

```
name.replace(
    /((?:.*?)two\]\[)([0-9]*)(.*)/g, 
    function(e,p1,p2,p3){
        //Adding the number with 2(As done in the question)
        return p1+(parseInt(p2)+2)+p3
    }
)
> "name[one][2][two][47][text]"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eW3gV6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var name = "name[one][1][two][45][text]";
// pattern for matching 2 or more digits inside [ and ]
var pattern = /\[([\d]{2,})\]/;
console.log(name.replace(pattern,"[47]");)
```